# Query regarding Developer Certification

Tags: certification

I have completed Dev401 certification an year back, now if I want to be "salesforce platform developer 1" certified do I need to take "salesforce platform developer 1" certification freshly or is there any transition exam from Dev401 to "salesforce platform developer 1"? Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Just got it, If you hold Developer 401, you can take a transition exam and get the App Builder certification. But if you want to take PD1 you have to write fresh right?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no transition exam, you have to directly take the Platform Developer I exam.

The Salesforce Certification website (http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers) states that

> The Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I credential is designed
>   for those who have knowledge, skills, and experience building custom
>   declarative and programmatic applications on the Force.com platform.

So you have experience building declarative applications, since you are DEV401 certified ;)

Now focus on the programmatic side (but do not forget the declarative side so far).

Carefully read the study guide (http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperI.pdf?v=8) as there are more topics than in the DEV401 exam.

You are expected to know Apex and Visualforce, SOQL, and even Lightning Components.

Think of this exam as if it was DEV501, without the programming assignment.

Hope this helps.